# Vertical position after navigating to hyperref hypertargets from hyperlinks seems too low

Tags: hyperref, pdf, links

The vertical scroll position after navigating to a `\hypertarget` from a `\hyperlink` (described in the [hyperref manual](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#TBL-21)) seems to be too low. The scroll position is at the baseline of the `\hypertarget`, so the target cannot be seen after clicking a `\hyperlink`.

If I run `latex -output-format pdf document.tex` twice on Mac OS X 10.8.2 to create a PDF from this document—

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,raiselinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\hyperlink{target1}{target1}
\hyperlink{target2}{target2}
%\hyperlink{target3}{target3}
\par\lipsum[1-7]
\lipsum*[8]
\hypertarget{target1}{target1}
\makeatletter\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{target2}{target2}}\makeatother
%\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{target3}{target3}}
\end{document}
```

—all the `\hyperlink`s in the resulting document navigate to the baselines of their respective `\hypertarget`s.

The example using `\Hy@raisedlink` is taken from [hypertarget seems to aim a line too low](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/hypertarget-seems-to-aim-a-line-too-low). The example using `\raisebox` is taken from the same question, but I’ve commented it out because it shows different (but still unexpected) behavior.

This question is related to [Certain hyperlinks (memoir+hyperref) placed too low](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59359/certain-hyperlinks-memoirhyperref-placed-too-low) and [hypertarget seems to aim a line too low](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/hypertarget-seems-to-aim-a-line-too-low), but I am asking it as a new question because I am not using memoir, and neither of the solutions described in [hypertarget seems to aim a line too low](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/hypertarget-seems-to-aim-a-line-too-low) seem to work for me.

This issue seems to be the very thing that the hyperref option [raiselinks](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#TBL-4) is intended to address, but that option appears to have no effect on the example document.

How should one make a `\hypertarget` (or equivalent) that is above the baseline?

One could, I suppose, use `\Hy@raisedlink` with an empty `\hypertarget` (that is, a `\hypertarget` with no associated text), but I’m hoping there’s a better way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The baseline is well known in TeX, but not the height of the
current line. Only TeX knows this at a later time, after paragraph breaking.
Measuring the height via boxing looses line breaking. `\vadjust pre` of
pdfTeX was (is?) not stable enough, some circumstances causes segmentation
faults. To some degree LuaTeX's attributes might help at the cost of a
complete different non-trivial implementation. Back to the question, the
current workaround is already mentioned (e.g. `\Hy@raisedlink` with empty
`\hypertarget`).